# Identify characters in a string by their relative position to a searched string?

Tags: python, html, regex, string, parsing

I'd like to identify the characters within a string that are located relatively to a string I search for.

In other words, if I search for 'Example Text' in the below string, I'd like to identify the immediate characters that come before and after 'Example Text' and also have '<' and '>'.

For example, if I searched the below string for 'Example Text', I'd like the function to return `<h3>` and `</h3>`, since those are the characters that come immediately before and after it.

```
String = "</div><p></p> Random Other Text <h3>Example Text</h3><h3>Coachella Valley Music &amp; Arts Festival</h3><strong>Random Text</strong>:Random Date<br/>"
```

Comment: How do you define "immediate characters that come before and after"? `<h3>` is 4 characters, while `</h3>` is 5. What if it was `<span id="example_text">`?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You should use an `xml` parser like `lxml` and do an xpath search by text. Any kind of html parsing with regex will only end in tears.

Comment: why are you parsing html with a regex?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I didn't realize html shouldn't be parsed with regex. I'll leave regex as a tag in case anyone makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you are asking the right question here. I think what you're actually aiming for is:

> Given a piece of text, how can I capture the html element that encapsulates it

Very different problem and one that should NEVER be solved with a regex. If you want to know why, just google it.

As far as that other question goes and capturing the relevant html tag I would recommend using `lxml`. The docs can be found [here](http://lxml.de/). For your use case you could do the follows:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO

>>> your_string = "</div><p></p> Random Other Text <h3>Example Text</h3><h3>Coachella Valley Music &amp; Arts Festival</h3><strong>Random Text</strong>:Random Date<br/>"

>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> document = etree.parse(StringIO(your_string), parser)
>>> elements = document.xpath('//*[text()="Example Text"]')

>>> elements[0].tag
'h3'
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: NameError: global name 'StringIO' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Reasons to **not** use regex:

- Difficulty in defining number of characters to return before and after match.
- If you match for tags, what do you do if the searched-for text is not immediately surrounded by tags?
- Obligatory: [Tony the Pony says so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

If you're parsing HTML/XML, use an HTML/XML parser. [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) is a good one, I personally prefer using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), as it uses `lxml` for some of its heavy lifting, but has other features as well, and is more user-friendly, especially for quick matches.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus as mentioned elsewhere, your code breaks with valid HTML fragments but invalid XML.

Comment: @heinst you are absolutely wrong in your last comment. Your answer is not robust. **That** is why I downvoted. If it had worked, I wouldn't have done that. Whining about SO sucking because it's working as intended is pointless.

Comment: @MattDMo I'd also like to note that this isn't really an answer... I assume you're going to delete it or add an answer to it?

Comment: @Slater and why isn't this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done by beautifulsoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

String = "</div><p></p> Random Other Text <h3>Example Text</h3><h3>Coachella Valley Music &amp; Arts Festival</h3><strong>Random Text</strong>:Random Date<br/>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(String)

input = 'Example Text'
for elem in soup(text=input):
    print(str(elem.parent).replace(input,'') )
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the regex `<[^>]*>` to match a tag, then use groups defined with parentheses to separate your match into the blocks that you want:

```
m = re.search("(<[^>]*>)Example Text(<[^>]*>)", String)
m.groups()
Out[7]: ('<h3>', '</h3>')
```